# Handling call back in angularjs from init method of another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

Lets say I am on Page A and I have line on Page A.

```
<a ng-click="sendNotification(notification)" href='#B'>Send Notification</a>
```

sendNotification method will make http post request and get some data.

Now on Page B I want to display data returned by sendNotification() method.

Approached I tried - after getting response to http request in sendNotification function, I am putting data in a service. And on load of Page B I am calling an init method will try to get data from service and initialize scope variables. 
But I gut problem this this approach is init method getting executed before http request returns.

How can I solve this? I don't want to make another HTTP request from init method of Page B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. I am redirecting from method sendNotification after http request's successCallBack, instead of redirecting onClick().

But better answer are welcome.